# Calling image in tkinter from PIL without save it

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have made a function that change the black colour of an image in png (a black icon with transparent background) to the colour of the accent theme in windows.
I use this function to made all my icons match the colour interface of my window, but with this function, I need to manually call the function to the image, and then, pick the image and define as a `PhotoImage` to put it as a `Label` in tkinter.
The goal of this, is to make a method to define the main png (the black icon) as a dynamic colour image that can be used as a `PhotoImage`, but even with the `Image.TkPhotoImage` method of the PIL library, I haven't done it.

The code of my function is this:

```
 def changeImageColorToAccentColor(imagename):
     imagename = str(imagename)
     accent = str(getAccentColor().lstrip('#'))


     rcolor = int(str(accent[0:2]),16)
     gcolor = int(str(accent[2:4]),16)
     bcolor = int(str(accent[4:6]),16)

     im = Image.open(str(imagename))
     im = im.convert('RGBA')

     data = np.array(im)   # "data" is a height x width x 4 numpy array
     red, green, blue, alpha = data.T # Temporarily unpack the bands for readability

     # Replace white with red... (leaves alpha values alone...)
     white_areas = (red == 0) & (blue == 0) & (green == 0) & (alpha == 255)
     data[..., :-1][white_areas.T] = (rcolor, gcolor, bcolor) # Transpose back needed

     im2 = Image.fromarray(data)
     image1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im2)
     return(image1)
```

And then, I define my Label in tkinter giving the `image` option the function that returns the PhotoImage object.

```
icon = Label(image=changeImageColorToAccentColor('file.png'))
```

But it doesn't work for me, so, if this proof doesn't work, I won't be able to make the object.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get the wrong image? Do you get an error? Does the program crash?

Comment: Sorry for my bad explaining. I get an error that shows me that the type of image is not compatible. I have solved yet. Thanks by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need ta save a reference to the `PhotoImage` object. If it gets garbage collected the image won't show. Passing it ti the `Label` as `image` parameter does not save a reference automatically. If you do

```
im = changeImageColorToAccentColor('image2.png')
icon = Label(root, image=im)
```

the `PhotoImage` object is saved as `im` and the image will show.

Comment: This works correctly. I know that I need to keep the reference, but I keep the reference in the function and not outside it.
Don't think that the problem is to keep the reference outside too.